# Where to find standard C++17 cmath file?

Tags: c++, standard-library, cmath

Where I can find original `cmath` or `math.h` files?

I need to use a comp_ellint_1(double) function in my program. It is declared in `C++17` standard in Special functions.

But my compilers(I tried `g++/clang++` etc.) [say this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IQS0.png).

I found out that in core files, where standard math.h and `cmath` are, there are no such functions declared in `cmath`. It looks like it is 99 standard...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your code and error messages directly to the question and not in images. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Are you compiling with *-std=c++17* or equivalent?

Comment: According to [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), they were shipped with GCC 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are available in gcc starting with version 7.1 and in clang starting with 3.9. You either have to upgrade your compiler, or use some other implementation (according to [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/comp_ellint_1), you can use [Boost.math](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/ellint/ellint_1.html)

Comment: I use macOs. All compilers are downloaded in DeveloperTools packages. How can I investigate what version I have?
Sorry, I'm novice :(

Comment: Not sure how it works on macOS, but try to open a terminal and do `clang -v`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  You need g++ version 7 or higher and you must specify `C++17` or higher.

```cpp
#include <ctgmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  double x = 0.5;
  double y = std::comp_ellint_1(x);
  std::cout << "x="<<x <<" -> y(x)="<<y <<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and ran as follows

```
$ g++ --std=c++17  test.cpp -o test
$ ./test
x=0.5 -> y(x)=1.68575
$
```

Incidentally, in Ubuntu 18.04, the headers are in `/usr/include/c++/n/tr1/` where `n=7,8, or 9` (major versions of g++ that support special math functions, as of Dec 2019)